# set specific strings in an array to bold

Tags: android, string

I am displaying the user's sms inbox as a listview. I'd like to bold the from and message strings, but since they are part of an array I haven't been able to find out how. I've tried using the  tags in the strings.xml but that doesn't work. How can I set these two strings to bold?

```
        public ArrayList fetchInbox() {  
        ArrayList sms = new ArrayList();  
        Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");  
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriSms, new String[]{"_id", "address", "date", "body"},null,null,null);   
        cursor.moveToFirst();  
        while  (cursor.moveToNext())  
        {  
               String address = cursor.getString(1);  
               String body = cursor.getString(3);
               sms.add(from + " " + address + "\n" + message + " " + body);
        }  
        return sms;  
    }

    private void setStrings() {
        from = (String) getResources().getString(R.string.from);
        message = (String) getResources().getString(R.string.message);
        }
```

Comment: I believe you need to do your formatting in the list view itself.  I would create an arraylist of string arrays and then display it in a custom listview with multiple controls each having individual formatting.  Googling custom listview should put you on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Html.fromHtml( String )` as such:

```
TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
txt.setText( Html.fromHtml( "<b>"+from+"</b> " + message ) );
```